# Angularjs does not show any output

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularJS. So, may be I am asking very naive question. I have downloaded angularjs 1.3.16 and tried to make a very basic example, which is as given below.  When I run in browser(chrome) it doesn't show any thing, while I am expecting, Input text box as well as Hello2 printed by its side.

```
    <html>
        <head>
          <script src="../angular-1.3.16/angular.min.js" />
        </head>
        <body ng-app>
            <input type="text">
            Hello {{2}}
        </body>
    </html>
```

I don't know, what wrong am I doing ? Please help me out. Moreover, any more things that I should keep in mind, while developing angularjs code to avoid silly errors, then let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't close your script tag

Try like this

```
<script src="../angular-1.3.16/angular.min.js" ></script>
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5IGt3FmPyMmQ4AIhGKpf?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the `script tag`. Make sure you are using a valid version with valid path

```
<script src="../angular-1.3.16/angular.min.js" ></script>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5BbDk6sBkLtkJAAOiQav?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-init like as
  close the tag as below

```
<script src="../angular-1.3.16/angular.min.js" ></script>
```

This good for writing script

```
   <body ng-app ng-init="firstName='Hello2'">
                <input type="text">
               {{ firstName }}
            </body>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z9DpzYl8Wz3kYe22gUd0?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Add App name in ng-app and close the script tag.

*e.g.*

```
<script src="../angular-1.3.16/angular.min.js"> </scrpt>

<body ng-app="myApp">
```